# FATAL EXCEPTION: main (map and routing program)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-maps

I got these errors.  My program is to read current location and route the map path.. Previously it worked on my Eclipse..which I checked them a month ago.. When I tried to run it again today it appears these errors... "Unfortunately FirstMap has stopped" can someone tell me what cause it? Is it because of the Eclipse? or SDK? or the api? I have tested for api 8 and 13..it doesn't work

Many thanks

```
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.android.map/my.android.map.MyMap}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1331)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:589)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:453)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at my.android.map.MyMap.onCreate(MyMap.java:104)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-18 02:53:14.372: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

My assumption solution:

As for now..the problem remain the same..

Im updating my sdk eclipse NOW..Once the update complete..Ill update (18.01.13-today) it here either its working or not..

Comment: when you are getting this error provide full log for more help

Comment: please look into them.. already did, many thanks